# Can I change the batch size in a yolo detection model in onnxruntime-web?

Tags: deep-learning, yolo, onnx

I am loading a yolov5 model with onnxruntime-web with onnx and then calling runInference(), I think I can get a speed-up per image using batches, but I don't see any support for batch size other than one.

Is it possible to set the batch size?